# Create Thread in Azure Web Role

Tags: windows, multithreading, azure, quartz.net

I need to create a scheduled task on my Azure web role. A small who delete entries in a SQL Azure DB. I thought about Quartz.net.
But I didn't find any way to create a thread on my Azure Web Role. How can I create a thread on my Azure Web Role ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your use-case you could setup an [startup task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx) (e.g. install quartz.net standalone and the required code you want to periodically run) or start of a task/thread/embedded quartz.net instance from [RoleEntryPoint.OnStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstart). Please also have a look at the many related questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916211/advantages-of-azure-workerrole-vs-starting-a-new-thread) to determine the pros/cons of running in IIS of the WebRole, starting tasks in the WebRole or hosting a separate WorkerRole.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will use a new thread for my case. Is there any tutorial about building a RoleEntryPoint with a web role ?

Comment: Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433030 for the basics. You just add a class implementing `RoleEntryPoint` to your WebRole project.

Comment: Typically there's already a WebRole.cs (if you're using the default template), so you just need to put code in there. Creating a new thread is done the same way as anywhere else.